# Steam web api show player items

Tags: php, api, steam

I am trying this URL:

[link](http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_%3C440%3E/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?SteamID=76561198031167040)

but i keep getting "404 not found" page..
i have entered the key i got from steam but no luck..
what should i do to make it work?

you can see this url for more information:
http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetPlayerItems

i just cant get it to work :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?SteamID=76561198031167040
```

It should be just `440`, not `<440>`

Comment: oh god >< i feel super dumb :P

Comment: Yeah it happens. Play around more next time.